# Fanuc Roboguide and ROS MoveIt Execution

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

My question concerns about specific details needed so that we can see movements that occur inside `ROS/MoveIt/Rviz` also in the simulated robot inside `Roboguide`.

Briefly, I use `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS bionic` and  `ros-melodic`.  I have **ROS/Moveit** respositories for fanuc. I downloaded, installed and built these repositories from [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver) under my `catkin_ws`.

On Windows side, I have installed `Roboguide`. I have followed  [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Installation) and  [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Configuration)  to make necessary configurations inside `Roboguide` on the virtual controller. When creating the work-cell, I chose `R-1000iA/80F` robot model.

On Linux side, specifically, I used `fanuc_r1000ia80f_moveit_config` repo.

On the TP, I have started the ROS TPE program. The following message appears:

```
38497     RSTA Waiting for ROS state prox
```

then I run the following on a terminal in ROS pc.

```
roslaunch fanuc_r1000ia_support robot_state_visualize_r1000ia80f.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.4 use_bswap:=false
```

Immediately, the following message appears on TP.

```
38499      RSTA Connected.
```

When I jog the robot in Roboguide. RVIZ shows the same movements.

Within `rviz`, using the motion planning plugin, I can `plan` a very simple movement specifying an end state. However, when I try to `execute`, it waits for a while and then `fails`.

I received the following errors on the terminal in my ROS PC.

```
    [ERROR] [1597341098.351110836]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ joint_1 joint_2 joint_3 joint_4 joint_5 joint_6 ]
[ERROR] [1597341098.351167409]: Known controllers and their joints:

[ERROR] [1597341098.351240102]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

Please, can you help me in this regard. Some suggestions or indicators to anything that may be the cause of this problem.

thanks,

Zahid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357050/fanuc-roboguide-and-ros-moveit-execution/) by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2020-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you only start the `robot_state_visualize_r1000ia80f.launch`, which allows you to *visualise the current state*, but nothing more, you cannot control motion.

---

Edit:

> I had added a `move_group` node in the launch file to be able to experiment with motion control

Do *not* edit the files in the support packages. For normal usage, there is no need. If you think you need to change something in them, it's most likely because you haven't configured something correctly.

Also: the `robot_state_visualize` does not start the necessary driver components to be able to command motion, even if you'd add `move_group` to the `.launch` file.

> However, later I used the following
>
> ```
> roslaunch fanuc_r1000ia80f_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.4 use_bswap:=false
> ```
>
> I was able to see the movements that I performed in `rviz` being done in `Roboguide`.

That would indeed be the correct `.launch` file to use for commanding the robot via MoveIt in Roboguide.

> But, now I am getting this error `TPIF-052 WARN FWD/BWD is disabled` and I cannot run the `ROS TP program` again.I had tried `FCTN->Abort All`, but it does not work.

You could see whether `FCTN->Disable FWD/BWD` helps.

But seeing as you write you could command the robot in Roboguide using MoveIt, there is nothing wrong with the ROS side, including `fanuc_driver`.

I would suggest you ask Fanuc about your problems with the Teach Pendant and/or your controller.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2020-08-14**:
thanks @gvdhoorn, I had added a `move_group` node in the launch file to be able to experiment with motion control. However, later I used the following

```
roslaunch fanuc_r1000ia80f_moveit_config moveit_planning_execution.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.4 use_bswap:=false
```

I was able to see the movements that I performed in `rviz` being done in `Roboguide`.  But, now I am getting this error `TPIF-052 WARN FWD/BWD is disabled` and I cannot run the `ROS TP program` again.I had tried `FCTN->Abort All`, but it does not work.